# WooCommerce: order from site A to B

Tags: woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to clone/create an order from site A to B. A bit like  but between 2 woocommerce stores. If an order is placed on site A I want that it shows in the woocommerce orders from site B.

I found something similar on [tutorialsinfo](https://www.tutorialsinfo.com/woocommerce-create-an-order-from-another-website/)

So I adapted that to what I needed, or at least I thought I did that. It seems I'm stuck with an error that I can't find, logs don't show much. I placed this code via php snipets on Site A with the API info from siteB.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'create_order_too_bsite', 10, 2 );

function create_order_too_bsite( $order, $data ) {
$live_ck = 'ck_siteB';
$live_cs = 'ck_siteB';
   $live_url = 'https://www.siteB.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/?consumer_key=' . $live_ck . '&consumer_secret=' . $live_cs;
   $customer = $data['billing'];

   $line_items = array();
   foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
      $line_items[] = array(
         'product_id' => $item->get_product_id(),
         'quantity'   => $item->get_quantity(),
      );
   }

   $billing = array(
      'first_name' => $customer->get_billing_first_name(),
      'last_name'  => $customer->get_billing_last_name(),
      'address_1'  => $customer->get_billing_address_1(),
      'address_2'  => $customer->get_billing_address_2(),
      'city'       => $customer->get_billing_city(),
      'state'      => $customer->get_billing_state(),
      'postcode'   => $customer->get_billing_postcode(),
      'country'    => $customer->get_billing_country(),
   );

   $shipping = array(
   'first_name' => $customer->get_shipping_first_name(),
   'last_name'  => $customer->get_shipping_last_name(),
   'address_1'  => $customer->get_shipping_address_1(),
   'address_2'  => $customer->get_shipping_address_2(),
   'city'       => $customer->get_shipping_city(),
   'state'      => $customer->get_shipping_state(),
   'postcode'   => $customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
   'country'    => $customer->get_shipping_country(),
);

// Controleer of er een ander verzendadres is aangegeven
if ( $order->get_shipping_address_1() !== $order->get_billing_address_1() ) {
   // Pas de verzendgegevens aan op basis van het aangegeven verzendadres
   $shipping = array(
      'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
      'last_name'  => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
      'address_1'  => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
      'address_2'  => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
      'city'       => $order->get_shipping_city(),
      'state'      => $order->get_shipping_state(),
      'postcode'   => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
      'country'    => $order->get_shipping_country(),
   );
}

 $body = array(
      'status'      => 'processing',
      'total'       => $order->get_total(),
      'billing'     => $billing,
      'shipping'    => $shipping,
      'line_items'  => $line_items,
      'meta_data'   => array(
         array(
            'key'   => 'createdby',
            'value' => 'siteA'
         )
      )
   );

   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url, array(
      'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
      'timeout' => 30,
      'body'    => json_encode( $body ),
   ) );
}
```

Love to have some tips to point me in the right direction.